# Solve third order differential equation that allows reduction of order

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

${ y'''(1+(y')^2)=2y''y' }$

What I was trying:

${ y' = z }$

${ z''(1+z^2)=2z'z }$

${ z' = t; z'' = \frac{dt}{dz}*\frac{dz}{dx} = t*\frac{dt}{dz} }$

${ t*\frac{dt}{dz}(1+z^2)=2tz; dt = \frac{2z}{1+z^2}dz }$

${ t = ln(z^2+1) + c_1; t = ln(c_1z^2+c_1)=z'}$

${ \frac{dz}{dx} = ln(c_1z^2+c_1) }$

${ x = \int{\frac{dz}{ln(c_1z^2+c_1)}} }$

And according to wolfram alpha "result found in terms of standart mathematical fuctions", but it has infinite series expansion. How can I solve it, is it even possible in simple way?

UPD: wolfram alpha does not give me answer when I'm trying to solve this equation entirely

Comment: I don't think you can even evaluate something like $\int \mathrm dx/\log x$ in elementary functions. If this is true, then your integral also is not elementary, since the integrand is of the form $$\frac{1}{\log(z+a)+\log(z+b)}.$$

Answer (score 1):

I think that's the closest you can get to a closed-form solution.
You have the general solution for $z$ implicitly in terms of an integral:

$$ \int \dfrac{dz}{\ln(c_1 z^2 + c_1)} = x + c_2 $$

but it seems the integral can't be done in closed form (it's certainly not elementary), and even if it could there's no guarantee you'd be able to invert it to get $z$ explicitly as a function of $x$, and then integrate that to get $y$.

Nonlinear differential equations rarely have closed-form solutions.  Even to have an implicit solution involving an integral is rare.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I think I will talk to my teacher about it then and ask if it was supposed to be like this.